# MS Excel VBA - Filtering by dates (excluding an entire year)

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for code that will be able to include all dates within a column except for an enire year (2016)

```
GRBReportSheet.Range("A" & IHRISFILTERFR & ":L" & IHRISFILTERLR).AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "12/31/2016")       'Filter by Start Date within 2016
```

The following code is filtering my report for all instances of 2016 but in a proceeding section I want to filter by all dates not in 2016. I know when filtering with other items I would use:

```
Criteria2:=">< Something"
```

Not sure how I can use this in a date array. Thank you greatly for your time!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two criteria in the `AutoFilter`:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, 
  Criteria1:="<01/01/16", 
  Operator:=xlOr, 
  Criteria2:=">12/31/16"
```

Here's an example of usage - may need tweaking to fit with your circumstances:

[image]

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<01/01/16", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">12/31/16"
```

Comment: Didn't even think about that! Thank you greatly

Comment: **Update, not sure why but even when I try this on my data filter it doesn't return anything even though there are plenty of entries before/on/after 2016. Tried converting the whole column to a date format and still no data.

Comment: I updated answer with working example of how I am using the `AutoFilter` - may need some tweak for your circumstances?

Comment: For some reason even with the operator being declared "xlOr" when I stop the code and walk though step by step and manually check the filter, it's applying an "And" operator. Code used as follows:

Comment: ' GRBReportSheet.Range("A" & IHRISFILTERFR & ":L" & IHRISFILTERLR).AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
                                xlFilterValues, Criteria1:="<01/01/16", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">12/31/16" '

Comment: Looking at the difference between the working example and yours maybe you should try exclude the `Operator:=_xlFilterValues` bit

Comment: Also - not knowing what region you are in - you might try using `">31/12/16"` as well. `">12/31/16"` worked for me in Australian English context but not sure this will work everywhere.

Comment: That was the ticket there! Had to take off the "Operator:=_xlFilterValues" bit..you are awesome Robin, thanks for helping me troubleshoot!

Comment: OK glad it helped :)